# How to use HTML5 color picker with event listener

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am looking for a way to use eventlisteners and getting every color change by moving the mouse over the palette. It works only without eventlistener and I would like to know why. Where is my mistake...

It works, if I use the following code. Moving the mouse over the palette, fires every color change.

HTML:

```
<input type="color" id='picker_1' oninput="getData(this.value)">
```

Javascript:

```
function getData(value){console.log(value);
```

Using an eventlistener, I get only values by opening or closing the picker, but not with moving over the palette.

HTML:

```
<input type="color" id='picker_1'>
```

Javascript:

```
let el = document.getElementById('picker_1');
el.addEventListener('oninput', function() {  // I tried also onchange
 console.log(el.value);
});
```

The best solution would be to use the standard HTML5 color picker with jQuery...

Happy for some help. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is no event as `oninput` when using `addEventListener`, you should remove the `on` prefix and use `input` instead.

```js
let el = document.getElementById('picker_1');
el.addEventListener('input', function() {  // I tried also onchange
 console.log(el.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="color" id='picker_1'>
```